Correcting a price axis label display error on an indicator
I have an indicator that plots horizontal price lines as well price
axis labels for up to 10 resistance levels and up to 10 support
levels. However the default settings in the pinescript code are that
only resistance levels 1 thru 6 and support levels 1 thru 6 are
enabled (checked) in the user control panel by default and the user
must manually enable (check) levels 7 thru 10 if they wish to also
display those.
However the problem is that even though resistance levels 7 thru 10
and support levels 7-10 are not enabled (checked) by default in the
user control panel and although the indicator is not displaying the
horizontal price lines for resistance levels 7 thru 10 and support
levels 7-10 it is still displaying the price axis labels for
resistance levels 7 thru 10 and support levels 7-10 - is there a way
to correct this by coding for default settings so that it only
displays the price axis labels AND the horizontal price lines for the
levels that are enabled (checked) in the user control panel and
displays neither for those levels that are not checked/enabled in
inputs section of user control panel?
I noticed that I can turn the individual price axis labels off
manually for individual levels in the style tab but I was looking for
a way to code it so that it only displays the horizontal lines as well
as the price axis labels for only those levels that are checked
enabled in the user control panel inputs section.
